# I need to show the monthly inventory data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table some thing like as follows for Inventory details.

### InventoryTable.

```
InventoryTableID  DateCreated  quantity  ItemName
-------------------------------------------------
1                 2010-02-04   12        abc
2                 2010-03-10   4         abc
3                 2010-03-13   5         xyz
4                 2010-03-13   19        def
5                 2010-03-17   15        abc
6                 2010-03-29   15        abc
7                 2010-04-01   22        xyz
8                 2010-04-13   5         abc
9                 2010-04-15   6         def
```

from the above table if my admin wants to know the inventory details for month April 2010 (i.e. Apr 1st 2010 - Apr 30th 2010)

I need the output as shown below.

1. inventory as on **Apr 1st 2010**

   ```
   ItemName  Datecreated   qty
   ----------------------------
   abc       2010-03-29    15
   xyz       2010-04-01    22
   def       2010-03-13    19
   ```
2. inventory as on **Apr 30th 2010**

   ```
   ItemName  Datecreated  qty
   ---------------------------
   abc       2010-04-13   5
   xyz       2010-04-01   22
   def       2010-04-15   6
   ```

Comment: I really don't catch the output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first result set, run with @YourDataParam = '2010-04-01'. For the second set, use '2010-04-30'.

```
;with cteMaxDate as (
    select it.ItemName, max(it.DateCreated) as MaxDate
        from InventoryTable it
        where it.DateCreated <= @YourDataParam
        group by it.ItemName
)
select it.ItemName, it.DateCreated, it.qty
    from cteMaxDate c
        inner join InventoryTable it
            on c.ItemName = it.ItemName
                and c.MaxDate = it.DateCreated
```